# form save POST action not routing to router in Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I loaded a form with endpoint:  http://localhost:3000/posts/newpost  -- GET

When I submit a form, its not redirecting to **posts/save_post** instead   its redirecting to http://save_post.

When I add posts in front of action, then the url is **http://localhost:3000/posts/posts/save_post**

```
form(role='form', enctype='multipart/form-data', action="/save_post",method="post", style='max-width: 250px;')

    //app.js

    const posts = require('./routes/post');
    app.use('/posts', posts);

    posts.js
    //get end point

    router.get('/newpost',function(req,res){
      res.render('new_post');
    });

    // post endpoint

    router.post('/save_post',function(req,res){
     console.log(req.body.paper_name);
    })
```

How can I call post route inside the post.js from Form?

Comment: have you tried using `save_post` instead of `/save_post`?

Comment: Hey,  Your answer fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `action="/save_post"` to `action="/posts/save_post"`.

Comment: In that case its routing to posts/posts/save_post

Comment: What's your HTML form submit button snippet ?

Comment: @Hareeshh also can you share how you are adding `posts` to the action . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error const posts = require('./routes/post'); If your file is posts.js it must be const posts = require('./routes/posts');